# direct access of terminating case of variadic template class works, but convenience class access fails compilation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The goal of the code below is to implement a histogram where the bucket limits are template parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "histogram.h"


int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
//histogram_tuple<5,10,15,std::numeric_limits<int>::max()> histogram;
histogram_tuple<5,10,15> histogram;

histogram.count ( 9 );
histogram.count ( 10 );
histogram.count ( 11 );
histogram.count ( 15 );

std::cout << sizeof ( histogram ) << std::endl;
std::cout << '<' << histogram.limit() << ' ' << histogram.count() << ", "
<< '<' << histogram.rest().limit() << ' ' << histogram.rest().count() << ", "
<< '<' << histogram.rest().rest().limit() << ' ' << histogram.rest().rest().count() << ", "
<< ' ' << histogram.rest().rest().rest().count()
<< std::endl;

std::cout << "====" << std::endl;

std::cout << '<' << bucket_limit<0>(histogram) << ':'
<< bucket_count<0>(histogram) << std::endl;
std::cout << '<' << bucket_limit<1>(histogram) << ':'
<< bucket_count<1>(histogram) << std::endl;
std::cout << '<' << bucket_limit<2>(histogram) << ':'
<< bucket_count<2>(histogram) << std::endl;
// std::cout << '<' << bucket_limit<3>(histogram) << ':'
//           << bucket_count<3>(histogram) << std::endl;
}
```

The above works fine. With the repeated rest() calls, the count of the final bucket (values >= 15) is printed.

However, when the final line of main() is uncommented, g++ 4.7.1 generates a compiler error that bucket_limit_entry<0u> and bucket_count_entry<0u> are incomplete.

Any advice on how to get the convenience functions bucket_limit<3> to compile, since the repeated rest() calls work?

Not really sure what's going on. Changing the index type to int and making the termination case -1 instead of 0 didn't work.

Here's histogram.h:

```
#pragma once

template <int ... Limits>
class histogram_tuple;

template<>
class histogram_tuple<>
{
int cnt_;
public:
histogram_tuple<>() :
cnt_ ( 0 )
{
}

void count ( int value )
{
++cnt_;
}

int count() const
{
return cnt_;
}
};


template <int First, int ... Rest>
class histogram_tuple <First,Rest...> :
private histogram_tuple<Rest...>
{
static const int limit_ = First;
int cnt_;
public:
histogram_tuple <First,Rest...>() :
cnt_ ( 0 )
{ }

int limit() const { return limit_; }

void count ( int value )
{
if ( value < limit_ )
++cnt_;
else
rest().count ( value );
}

int count() const
{
return cnt_;
}

const histogram_tuple<Rest...>& rest() const
{
return *this;
}

histogram_tuple<Rest...>& rest()
{
return *this;
}
};


template <unsigned index, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_count_entry;

template <int First, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_count_entry<0,First,Limits...>
{
static int value(histogram_tuple<First,Limits...> const& histogram)
{
return histogram.count();
}
};

template <unsigned index,int First, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_count_entry<index,First,Limits...>
{
static int value(histogram_tuple<First,Limits...> const& histogram)
{
return bucket_count_entry<index-1,Limits...>::value(histogram.rest());
}
};

template <unsigned index,int ... Limits>
int bucket_count( histogram_tuple<Limits...> const& histogram )
{
return bucket_count_entry<index,Limits...>::value(histogram);
}


template <unsigned index, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_limit_entry;

template <int First, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_limit_entry<0,First,Limits...>
{
static int value(histogram_tuple<First,Limits...> const& histogram)
{
return histogram.limit();
}
};

template <unsigned index,int First, int ... Limits>
struct bucket_limit_entry<index,First,Limits...>
{
static int value(histogram_tuple<First,Limits...> const& histogram)
{
return bucket_limit_entry<index-1,Limits...>::value(histogram.rest());
}
};

template <unsigned index,int ... Limits>
int bucket_limit( histogram_tuple<Limits...> const& histogram )
{
return bucket_limit_entry<index,Limits...>::value(histogram);
}
```

Comment: by the way, please indent your code.  It would make it somewhat less painful to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <int First, int ... Limits>
bucket_limit_entry<0,First,Limits...>
```

won't match

```
bucket_limit_entry<0>
```

because `First` won't match nothing. (`...Limits` matches nothing, but `First` can only match one `int`).

So you need to add an additional template for the case where you've run out of limits:

```
template<>
struct bucket_limit_entry<0>
```

When you do that, you'll find that `histogram<>::limit()` is undefined, but you can easily fix that.

You'll need to do the same with bucket_count_entry, except that `histogram<>::count()` is defined.

The fact that you can't just define `template<int...Limits> struct bucket_limit_entry<0, Limits...> {...}` is a bit odd. The problem, as I understand it, is that both "`Index` is 0" and "`Limits...` has at least one element", are restrictions on the general template, and there is no arbitrary ordering between them. Consequently, `template<int...Limits> struct X<0, Limits...>` and `template<unsigned index, int First, int...Rest> struct X<index, First, Rest...>` are not ordered by the partial ordering for template specialization, and when both of them apply, you end up with an ambiguity.

But it seems to me that there is a simpler solution, since you can let the type of the `histogram_tuple` just be deduced:

```
template<unsigned Index> struct bucket_limit_entry {
    template<typename Hist>
    static int value(Hist const& histogram) {
        return bucket_limit_entry<Index-1>::value(histogram.rest());
    }
};

template<> struct bucket_limit_entry<0> {
    template<typename Hist>
    static int value(Hist const& histogram) {
        return histogram.limit();
    }
};

template<unsigned index, typename Hist>
int bucket_limit(Hist const& histogram ) {
    return bucket_limit_entry<index>::value(histogram);
}
```

Comment: That's one of a few things I tried. Still a compilation error...ambiguous class template instantiation.

Comment: That works great. Obviously I need to work on my template-fu.